# AWS SAM deploy with optional Transform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, datadog, aws-sam

I'm trying to integrate Datadog with my SAM Lambdas function. Integration with Datadog requires some additional stuff [DataDog documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/installation/python/?tab=awssam). I'm using one *template.yaml* file and I have 3 envs with conditionals statements... I don't want to deploy my changes to PROD env. I know that the best solution would be to use separate *template.yaml* file for each env but Jenkins configuration does not allow to use *template.yaml* file in this way...
Unfortunately **Condition** is not allowed in the section **Transform**...

Below my example:

```
Transform: 
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
  - Name: DatadogServerless
    Parameters:
      stackName: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
      pythonLayerVersion: 71
      extensionLayerVersion: 41
      site: "datadoghq.com"
      apiKeySecretArn: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:111111111111:secret:datadog-api-key-XXXXX"
    Condition: IsProd
Description: >
  sam-app-datadog

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app-datadog

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: The deployment environment (probably the AWS account)
    Default: dev
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
    - 'dev'
    - 'stage'
    - 'prod'

Conditions:
    IsDev: !Equals [!Ref Environment, 'dev']
    IsStage: !Equals [!Ref Environment, 'stage']
    IsProd: !Equals [!Ref Environment, 'prod']


Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Policies:
      - Statement:
        - Sid: AllowReadDatadogApiKey
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
          Resource: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:111111111111:secret:datadog-api-key-XXXXX'
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
  FooBarFunction:
    Condition: IsProd
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: foo.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Policies:
      - Statement:
        - Sid: AllowReadDatadogApiKey
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
          Resource: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:111111111111:secret:datadog-api-key-XXXXX'
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        FooBar:
          Properties:
            Path: /foo
            Method: get

Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
  FooBarApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for FooBar function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/foo/"
    Condition: IsProd
  FooBarFunction:
    Description: "FooBar Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt FooBarFunction.Arn
    Condition: IsProd
  FooBarFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for FooBar function"
    Value: !GetAtt FooBarFunctionRole.Arn
    Condition: IsProd
```

Does anyone have any idea how to install Datadog stuff based on the ENV with only one *template.yaml* file??

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the secret ARN as a parameter:

```
  DataDogSecretArn:
    Type: String
    Description: DataDog secret ARN
```

and then reference it in the transform:

```
    Parameters:
      stackName: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
      pythonLayerVersion: 80
      extensionLayerVersion: 48
      site: "datadoghq.com"
      apiKeySecretArn: !Ref DataDogSecretArn
```